# dask - how to set a local distributed scheduler as the default scheduler for dask.dataframe?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I was trying to make dask.dataframe to use a local distributed scheduler by default, but it's not clear to me from reading the Dask document on how to do that. Does something like below suffice?

```
from dask import distributed
from dask import dataframe as dd
client = distributed.Client(processes=True)  # use multi processing
dask.config.set(scheduler=client)

dd.merge(df1, df2, on='some_col')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does: if you create a distributed `Client` of any sort, it will become the default scheduler for further Dask computation.